# Ajax call not working in Servlets?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make an Ajax call from my JSP to Servlet and then get the data from the servlet and embed it to the html view. For now the data is not even being added to my  tags after the ajax call. What could I be doing wrong ? Is there a better way to do it? Any suggestions or advise is really appreciated.

HomeServlet.java
package com.example;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Home
 */
@WebServlet("/HomeServlet")
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HomeServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<>();

          String text = "some text";
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         response.setContentType("text/html");
         out.println("<html><body>");
         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/apiprovider","root","");
             Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from apiinfo");
            // out.println("<table border=1 width=50% height=50%>");
            // out.println("<tr><th>EmpId</th><th>EmpName</th><th>Salary</th><tr>");
             while (rs.next()) {
                 String n = rs.getString("apiname");
                 String nm = rs.getString("apiendpoint");

                 options.put("value1", n);
                 options.put("value2", nm);
                 String json = new Gson().toJson(options);





                 response.setContentType("application/json");
                 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                 response.getWriter().write(json);

                // out.println("<tr><td>" + n + "</td><td>" + nm + "</td><td>" + s + "</td></tr>"); 
             }
           //  out.println("</table>");
            // out.println("</html></body>");
             con.close();
            }
             catch (Exception e) {
             out.println("error");
         }
     }



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //doGet(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
        String n = request.getParameter("apiname");
        String p = request.getParameter("apiendpoint");
        String e = request.getParameter("apiversion");
        String c = request.getParameter("source");
        try
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("driver loaded");
        System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
        Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/apiprovider","root","");
        System.out.println("Connection created");
        PreparedStatement ps= ((java.sql.Connection) con).prepareStatement("insert into apiinfo(apiname,apiendpoint,apiversion,accessibility) values (?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,n);
        ps.setString(2,p);
        ps.setString(3, e);
        ps.setString(4,c);
        ps.execute();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Inserted");
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
        System.out.println(e1);
        }

    }

}
```

Home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ajaxresponse">

</div>
<form>
 API Name:<br>
  <input type="text" id = "apiname" name="apiname">
   API ENDPOINT:<br>
  <input type="text" id ="apiendpoint" name="apiendpoint">
  <br>
  API VERSION:<br>
  <input type="text" id="apiversion" name="apiversion">
   ACCESSIBLE:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="internet"> Internet<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="source" value="vpn"> VPN<br>
 <!-- 
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" formaction="Home" method="post" value="Submit"> -->
  <br>
    <input type="submit" id="check" name="check" value="Check">

</form> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", "#check", function() { // When HTML DOM "click" event is invoked on element with ID "somebutton", execute the following function...
   console.log("I was clicked");
    $.get("HomeServlet", function(responseText) { 

        // Execute Ajax GET request on URL of "someservlet" and execute the following function with Ajax response text...
      var $select = $("#ajaxresponse");                           // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "someselect".
        $select.find("option").remove();                          // Find all child elements with tag name "option" and remove them (just to prevent duplicate options when button is pressed again).
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {    
            // Iterate over the JSON object.
            $("<option>").val(key).text(value).appendTo($select); // Create HTML <option> element, set its value with currently iterated key and its text content with currently iterated item and finally append it to the <select>.
        });       // Locate HTML DOM element with ID "somediv" and set its text content with the response text.
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the check button. This is what shows up in the url.

```
http://localhost:8080/TestApplication/Home.jsp?apiname=&apiendpoint=&apiversion=&check=Check
```

Comment: Try debugging on browser and see if you are getting data from ajax call or not

Comment: Have you check that your servlet is found or not?